# http://www.servername & http://servername redirect to https://servername not working

Tags: redirect, nginx

We have a server called servername.com, if anyone goes to http://servername.com or http://www.servername.com we want them redirected to **https://servername.com**

Here's thenginx redirect block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.servername.com servername.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://servername.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

**http://www.servername.com** is getting redirected to **https://servername.com** while **servername.com** is **not** getting redirected to **https://servername.com**

I have a seperate 443 block to handle https which works fine for **https://servername.com**. So if anyone goes directly to **https://servername.com** everything works fine. But all entries coming to **servername.com** or **servername.com/demo** are failing.

I tried separating out www.servername.com and servername.com as seperate blocks, same issue still persists.

How do I send **http://servername.com** or **servername.com** traffic to **https://servername.com** ?

Edit: 16th May 2017

Edited Server block as rewrite is depricated/not recommended

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.servername.com servername.com;
            return 301 https://servername.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Test the `nginx` configuration using `nginx -T`.

Comment: IT passes the test. After making changes I normally do a sudo nginx -s reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to DNS records getting changed on the hosting provider's side.
By default the provider doesn't allow one domain name to have 2x DNS addresses. But in this case there were 2 entries pointing to 2 locations. The entry got added on the hosting provider's end and was not pointing to the correct server or was pointing to 2 different places, they didn't take the blame and pointed out that a user must have done it on our end. However, when anyone went to https://servername.com or https://www.servername.com they landed on the correct landing page at https://servername.com, non https requests were not going anywhere in chrome but working fine with Mozilla Firefox.

Anyways, if you end up with this issue, 1st thing you can do is, check where the DNS is pointing & then fiddle with nginx/apache.